# How to set div height to 100% of chosen print paper?

Tags: css, printing

How can I set the height to 100% of chosen print paper?

**CSS**

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 0px !important;
border: 1px solid;
```

When I print in Google Chrome, the printed div will only be as high as the content in the div.

Is it possible to make a div as high as chosen paper size?

Comment: give it an absolute position and set top: 0px & botton: 0px;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
width: 100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 0px !important;
border: 1px solid;
```

also, if position absolute won't work you can do the same with position:fixed; this will work but might do some more damage to your layout, depending on how everything is arranged :)

I'll edit this to make it more obvious, so... if you are  using position fixed and you have multiple pages they will just go one on top of the other so that wouldn't be right... but in order to get the right result with position absolute you have to keep in mind that the css style here will take 100% of the height, but it's the height of it's parent... so if the parent is the body just add `html, body{ height:100% };`

Comment: This one worked pretty good. But i have seperated the page in "page-breaks" and now only 1 page is showing for print...

Comment: I'm guessing you used position:fixed; and since you have more pages they overlapped.. you have to combine the answers here, add the height to the body & html to 100%, leave the div to absolute position and the rest as it is (top and bottom 0px) - you need to have this div as the first child of the body doe... otherwise it will just take the height of its parent :)

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case I also needed these styles:
`left:0px;margin-left: 0px !important;`

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way I found to do this was use Viewport units and `page-break-after:always`. This works well for printing multiple pages.

I suggest structuring your HTML like this:

```
<div class="someContainerClass">
  <section id="pageOne"></section>
  <section id="pageTwo"></section>
  <section id="pageThree"></section>
</div>
```

And using this CSS:

```
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

This way you can contain your content in the page it needs to be.

Comment: 100vh only works when you disable margins in page settings. Otherwise your elements will overflow the page.

Comment: Thanks, I did add a bottom margin to prevent this from happening but removing all margins would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can use `@page` to manipulate page settings. Works for FF and Chrome at least.

Comment: Best solution, however this messes up the FF print *preview*

Comment: "100vh only works when you disable margins in page settings."
This doesn't look to be true anymore in Chrome!

Answer (score 11):

If you add a page break to the end, the element will extend to the bottom of the last page.
It's particularly useful if you want a footer to appear at the bottom of the last page:

```
<div style='position:relative;overflow:hidden;background:#ffe!important'>
    <div style='margin-bottom:200px'>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
    <div style='page-break-before:always'></div>
    <div style='position:absolute;bottom:0'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

This won't give you an extra blank page - so long as you don't have any content after the page break (the absolutely positioned footer doesn't count, unless it somehow spills onto the second page). Watch out for margins which extend outside the body!

Comment: I don't know about the original question but this is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: thanks, This work when you try to print an HTML page and want your footer at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at media queries.

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

So you can change output without messing up your screen layout

Answer (score 4):

I was having a problem with setting the height to fill the page as it would always produce a blank second page when I only wanted a single page. Then I realised this is because of the print margins.

These margins are not standardised across browsers but you can specify them yourself in CSS:

```
@page {
    margin: 10mm;
}
```

You then need to subtract the margins from the total height to fit the content into a single page, i.e.:

```
.fit-to-page {
    height: calc(100vh - 20mm);
}
```

This will fit exactly one page and adjusts to the page size and orientation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your body 100% this should work.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This needs to be done because as you know your content is within the body. The body does not have a default height of 100%, so the bodys height will just adapt to the content within itself, unless you manually give it a height like shown in the example above.

Comment: My upv but you may want to also explain _why_