# Margin with CSS on page breaks

Tags: html, css, margin, page-break

I'm working on a small personal website that also needs to be printable. The site itself is structured in a simple way: `body` serves as a backdrop, has a single container child that has a fixed width (and some styling, padding, etc.), and within this container, I have several sections (`<div class="section">`). During print, I'd rather not break up these sections, unless necessary (thus, `.section` has a style addition `page-break-inside: avoid;`). Obviously if such a section cannot fit into a single page, it will have a page-break on the inside, but otherwise will slide the element to the next page.

This part is working fine, however after a page break, I'd still like the next element to align properly to the page top, with its default margin. But this is not happening. Whenever I prepare for a print, the margin on top of `.section` elements that get pushed to the next page disappear - even though it shouldn't, unless my understanding of page breaks and margins is incorrect (which might be the case).

I've prepared a small example:

```css
body {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
  margin: 0;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin: 16px auto;
  padding: 2.5% 0;
  max-width: 200mm;
  line-height: 1.1;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.container>.section {
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 5% 2.5%;
  min-height: 500px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px #AA888888;
}

.container>.section:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0%;
}

.container>.section:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.section-red {
  background-color: #f44336;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.section-green {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.section-blue {
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.section-yellow {
  background-color: #c0ca33;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.section-orange {
  background-color: #ffb300;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.section-pink {
  background-color: #e91e63;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.section-purple {
  background-color: #9c27b0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.font-size-large {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.font-size-xlarge {
  font-size: 18px !important;
}

@media print {

    body {
        width: 210mm;
    }

    .container {
        max-width: 90%;
        min-width: 0;
        margin: 5mm auto 200mm;
    }

    .container > .section {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    .container > .section > section {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container font-size-large">
      <div class="section section-red">
      </div>
      <div class="section section-blue">
      </div>
      <div class="section section-green">
      </div>
      <div class="section section-purple">
      </div>
      <div class="section section-orange">
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

You might need to copy it to a local HTML and CSS file to have it printed properly, though.

EDIT:

Quick visual example of the issue.

Regular page, no breaks (expected layout):
[image: unbroken layout]

Broken layout during print:
[image: broken layout]

Comment: Printing from the web across computers and browsers can be hard to nail down. Have you tried applying padding or margins to the body element instead of the sections? There is also a page-break-before style if this is helpful.

Comment: Due to different paper sizes, I'd rather not have fixed break points in the content, but have it dynamically assigned during print. I also don't see how adding a margin to `body` would fix the child's positioning (if you check the sample code you'll see that `.container` acts like an actual visual container, adding contrast to the gray backdrop with its own white background, breaking this would screw up the layout).

Comment: Copy that fiddle code into a snippet right in the question (hit CTRL-M) while editing to add one or click that icon

Comment: Thanks, added it as an inline sample, however printing here is still broken - to observe the effect I'm having, you'll still need to copy the snippet to a local HTML file and print it from there.

Comment: I came across this other post which discusses scaling a div to fill the paper if you needed to scale the previous section to fill the page.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690580/how-to-set-div-height-to-100-of-chosen-print-paper.  This might help with a section that thinks it already has top margin when its on a new page. I still think you might try body margins to see if that helps get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution from a related context [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/#box-decoration-break), that works for this scenario aswell.
[box-decoration-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break):clone is used to "copy" css-attributes when a line-, column or page-break occures. And the latter is the case here, scince margin and/or padding are among the copied properties.
(It's widely supported except of iexplore.)

All I had to do was adding that property to my print-css, to have a fixed header an a repeating padding for the main-element (that would be your .container) on every page:

```
@media print {

    header {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    main{
        padding: 4cm 2cm 2cm 2cm;
        box-decoration-break: clone;
    }
...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a reliable way to do this for `<div>` based layouts using headless chrome/chromium printing. (I realize table based layouts are slighly different, I haven't needed those yet)

The problem is when you add margin to a div and it `breaks` onto the next page, the margin does not get applied above because of how the box model behaves. And padding is only applied internally, so you end up with this:

[image]

The solution I found was to wrap your container in another div, and add some padding to that element instead:

[image]

In tailwind this is as easy as wrapping your container with `<div class="pt-4 first:pt-0">`

Pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

Use another container with small padding will fix this, [gist](https://gist.github.com/steelywing/01267d7104236814632e9fb4478ce7ad) / [demo](https://gistpreview.github.io/?01267d7104236814632e9fb4478ce7ad)

The demo page 2 is with extra container, page 3 is without extra container.

[image]

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div {
            border-radius: 1rem;
        }

        .section {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: white;
            padding: 2rem;
            margin: 40px auto;
            height: 60%;
            width: 60%;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #999; height: 100%;">
    <div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 1rem; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="section" style="background-color: green;">
            Page 1
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 1px;">
            <div class="section" style="background-color: blue;">
                Page 2 with extra container
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" style="background-color: red;">
            Page 3 without extra container
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```