# Avoid text overlapping footer when printing multiple pages

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a page to be printed that contains text and a footer

If the text is spanning multiple pages, it overlaps the footer when printing

How can I avoid this?

css

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">Name</div>
        <div class="col-10">{{ name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">Age</div>
        <div class="col-10">{{ age }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">Notes</div>
        <div class="col-10">{{ notes }}</div>
    </div>
 </div>


<div class="container">
    <footer class="align-items-center">
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="col-6 text-center"></div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">Name<br>Name2</div>
        </div>
        <hr style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                       Address
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

I tried setting the footer as a background image to body and adding `margin` to `@page` but these margins affect the background image too

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property **break-inside** (replacing page-break-inside) [MDN Web DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside) and **break-after** (replacing page-break-after) [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

With that you can add a page break before the footer on each page. So the footer doesn't get overlap by your content.

```css
footer {
  break-after: always;
  background-color: white;
}
```

And then to avoid splitting the content/element:

```css
.row {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

You may need to doublecheck if your users / visitors on what browser they are using :

[Can I use CSS break-after](https://caniuse.com/?search=break-after)

[Can I use CSS break-inside](https://caniuse.com/?search=break-inside)

**Update:**

Or you can try using the `@media print`. I use it on project before. [@media print](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm)

```css
@media print {
  footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .container.content {
    padding-bottom: 140px; /* adjust this value to match the height of your footer plus some extra padding */
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately when printing the page, using chrome and firefox latest versions

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully that works. I used it before to print out certain element / container

Comment: When the element spans multiple pages the padding works at the end of the element not at half where the page ends

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71111189/13564342) worked for me. The key was using `box-decoration-break` and setting `padding-bottom` to the height of my footer in the css for the main page content. E.g.:

```
main {
    padding-bottom: 2cm;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```